# Date conversion in SQL Server keeps failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a date column in a table (format `yyyymmdd`) but it's stored as `nvarchar`. I'm trying to convert it to a `date` and clean it up using either one of the following scripts:

```
convert(varchar(10), cast(ltrim(rtrim(replace([mydate], ''"'', ''''))) as datetime), 112) [mydate]

convert(nvarchar, cast(ltrim(rtrim(replace([mydate], ''"'', ''''))) as datetime), 112) [mydate]
```

The table contains tens of thousands of rows.

I get the following error constantly:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you use the `Try_Cast()` function and see what input values return a `NULL` result.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (DateString NVARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('20160101')
,('20160230')

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       DateString
       ,ISDATE(DateString) as IsDate
       ,TRY_CONVERT(DATE,DateString,112) as DateFieldTryConvert
       ,CASE WHEN ISDATE(DateString) = 1 THEN CAST(DateString AS DATE) END as DateFieldCaseExpression
    FROM
       @Table
)

SELECT
    *
    ,FORMAT(DateFieldCaseExpression, 'yyyymmdd') as DateFormatedToString
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateFieldCaseExpression,112) as DateConvertedToString
FROM
    cte
```

John Provided some good information but I thought I would expand a little for you.

- First thing to know you need SQL 2012+ for TRY_CONVERT() and FORMAT(), those are also .Net functions being called via SQL so they can introduce poor performance when applied to larger data sets in particular.
- IsDate() function is a SQL function that doesn't have huge performance impacts and will let you know if SQL can interpret the string as a legitimate date. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx
- Next a Date DATA TYPE doesn't have a format inherently it is all of the formats mm/dd/yyyy, yyyymmdd, etc. how that is represented will depend on your computer's regional settings and settings in SSMS, to represent as a string then you would cast/convert it back to what you want.
- Fourth and perhaps most importantly the error you are receiving suggests that you have bad data in that column which is not actually in yyyymmdd format or is an incorrect date such as 2/30/2016 in my example as there are not 30 days in February.
- Finally if you are converting I would recommend storing and keeping the conversion as part of a schema change, if you are allowed to.  Because storing dates as text is really a bad idea for the reason such as the error you are receiving and means to filter based on range etc. you always have to convert to a date which will be more costly on your queries.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Bad data indeed! The data column has a couple of messy values which caused the problem. Appreciate your time and your help.

Comment: @Jasu glad to help, if you have gotten what you need please upvote answers that helped you and accept an answer that got you what you needed that way points are awarded and others know you have answered your question.  cheers

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be over thinking this

```
Declare @String nvarchar(25) = '20161121'
Select cast(@String as date)
```

Returns

```
2016-11-21
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I would need to keep the output in the same format, i.e. yyyymmdd. Just the nvarchar needs to be converted to date.

Comment: @Jasu any conversion of a date to desired format will result in a string representation of that date.  So, convert(varchar(10),cast(MyDate as date),112) will return a varchar in the format of yyyymmdd

Comment: @Jasu  Now, you may have some bogus data.  To check for this 
Select * From YourTable where try_convert(date,MyDate,112) is null

Comment: Thanks John, issue solved. Took some time to find out that a couple of values in the date column were messy, and hence caused the error.

Comment: @Jasu well done.  Risky storing dates as strings.  Sooner or later it will bite you

Answer (score 0):

Simple date-conversion method in SQL:

```
DECLARE @datevar VARCHAR(8) 

SET @datevar = '20161122' 
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, @datevar, 112),'-','')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention that your date format is "**yyyymmdd**". An you are using 112 code for date convertsion in query which is also correct because it accept date in "**yyymmdd**" format. So there is no issue with query.

But if input data in convert method is wrong then it create an issue. For example

If I run below query . It work fine because dd=11 and mm=22 that is correct with format.

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast(ltrim(rtrim(replace('20161122', '"', ''))) as datetime), 112) [mydate]
```

But if my query is like this . Here I put 22 in place of mm . That create an issue because max value for mm is 12.

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast(ltrim(rtrim(replace('20162211', '"', ''))) as datetime), 112) [mydate]
```

So there is no issue with query. The issue is generate due to wrong data in that table.

Hope this will help you :)